I can use Mapbox Android SDK even though the gradle information is not correct. Is there an error?
Even though SDK_REGISTRY_TOKEN or mapbox username is not correct, I can use the sdk. Is there a problem with Mapbox? I will take the application live. This is why there is a trust issue.
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = SDK_REGISTRY_TOKEN
            }
        }


I applied the information in the documentation. I entered the information incorrectly. I used Mapbox SDK without any problems. I entered the information correctly. I was able to use the Mapbox SDK again.
